# ShareLaTeX doesn't sync correctly with Git repo upon Pull

Tags: git, github, latex

I am using the ShareLaTeX Github integration to version control my thesis. I love the basic workflow but have recently been running into a situation where file name changes in the remote repo don't correctly propagate into the ShareLaTeX version of the repo. For example, I initially had a file called `filter.jl`, which synced fine between my local repo, the Github remote version, and the ShareLaTeX version. I then renamed the file to `fun_filter.jl`; the change appears correctly on Github, but when I pull the changes into ShareLaTeX and at a later point push changes from ShareLaTeX to Github again, the file is again renamed to `filter.jl`.

Has anyone had similar experiences? How can I deal with merge conflicts on the ShareLaTeX side? It really shouldn't be a problem because ShareLaTeX doesn't change the same files that my computer changes locally, so all of the merges should work automatically.

If anyone has had a similar experience or has got an idea what I could be doing wrong, answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: My only explanation would be that your change was somehow lost during a merge, i.e. the old filename version of things was retained.  Either that, or your change never actually got merged.